¿Cómo hago un Script con JavaScript en Unity?
Necesito formular una pregunta de principiante.
Estoy haciendo un curso de Unity online y me he quedado atascado cuando me dicen que haga un Script con JavaScript. La única opción que he visto es hacerlo con C#, pero no me aparece la opción de hacerlo con JS. ¿Es posible que sea porque en el curso usa una versión distinta de Unity respecto de la mía? La versión de Unity que usa el profe es más antigua.
Cualquier apunte al respecto es bienvenido.
Gracias

Bienvenido. Puedo decirte que en versiones antiguas de Unity se permitia lenguaje de scripting alternativo de C# y JavaScript. Pero Si estas haciendo un curso, deberias de preguntarle al profe. En este sitio estoy seguro que te ayudaran, pero deberias de repasar como elaborar una pregunta. y ofrecer lo que has intentado. Esto es un sitio de voluntarios que te daran apoyo con tus errores, no creo que elaboren un trabajo para ti. Quiza te has adelantado al curso que estas haciendo o te saltaste alguna clase donde explican como lo que aquí preguntas

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Unity no tiene Javascript para el desarrollo de scripts, tiene uno similar llamado UnityScript que es un lenguaje modelado a partir de JavaScript.
Esto lo puedes mirar en la documentación de Unity
https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html
Espero haberte ayudado.

En 2024 solo soporta C# y una especie de Blueprints. Si prestas atención esa documentación es de Unity 5.4 que salió hace 7 años.
